# Get selected text with a div, with arbitrary nested divs

Tags: javascript

Using javascript, I'd like to get the selected text within a div. My question is almost the same as [Get selected text from only one div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529530/get-selected-text-from-only-one-div) except that within the div there may be an arbitrary number of other nested divs. The answer to that question only works for one nested div.

In other words, say I have a div, STUFF. STUFF could be arbitrary HTML, including plenty of other nested divs. I want the selected HTML within the forkfork div, including any selected nested divs.

Updated: Here's some code, adapted from the previous question. I want to be able to select anything within the "forkfork" div, and have it returned, ideally the raw HTML.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="forkfork">want to be able to select anthing within here
    <div id="child">or in here</div>
    <div id="child1">perhaps in here,
        <div id="child2">maybe in here,
            <div id="child3">or in here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    though here.
</div>
<div id="b">don't want to have this returned.</div>

<button id="btn">btn
<script>
function select() {
    var flag = 0;
    sel = window.getSelection();
    for (var i = 0; i < sel.rangeCount; i++) {
        var s = sel.getRangeAt(i).startContainer.parentNode.id;
        var e = sel.getRangeAt(i).endContainer.parentNode.id;
        if (s == "forkfork") flag = 1;
        if (flag = 1 && e == "forkfork" || e == "child") flag = 2;
    }

    if (flag == 2) alert(sel);

}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    select();
});
</script>
</body>
```

And a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4n3ud3nb/1/

Comment: Could you provide example code?

Comment: If you select only 'rhaps in her' What should happen? If you select only the upper part: 'nt to be able to select ' piece. What should happen? Do you get the whole 'div' if you select 'or in here' ? Or is just if you click on the div you get the total selection inclusive deeper divs?

Comment: I only want the selected text, regardless of where in the nested diff structure it occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cloneContents()` from the range the contents of the selection could be returned.

The first `cloneContents` call will return the contents if there was an over run of our targeted element `forkfork`.

If we find no over run of the selection, we will check to make sure our selection starting range is a child of the targeted element.

#### Here is the example snippet:

```js
function select(event) {
  var sel;
  //console.log(document.getSelection);
  if (document.getSelection) 
    sel = document.getSelection();
  else
    sel = document.selection.createRange();
  //console.log('sel',sel);
  var selText = '';
  var forkfork = document.getElementById("forkfork");
  if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var clonedSelection = range.cloneContents().querySelector("#forkfork");
    if (clonedSelection) {
      selText = clonedSelection.innerHTML;
    } else {
      clonedSelection = range.cloneContents();
      var startNode = sel.getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentNode;
      //console.log(isChild(startNode, forkfork));
      if (isChild(startNode, forkfork)) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.appendChild(clonedSelection);
        selText = div.innerHTML;
      }
    }
  }

    alert(selText.toString());
}

function isChild(child, parent) {
  if (child === parent) return true;
  var current = child;
  while (current) {
    if (current === parent) return true;
    current = current.parentNode;
  }
  return false;
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", select);
```

```css
#a {
  background: #C0D9AF;
}
#b,#b2 {
  background: #ECC8EC;
}
#c {
  background: #AFEEEE;
}
```

```html
<div id="b">don't want to have this returned.</div>
  <div id="forkfork">want to be able to select anthing within here
    <div id="child">or in here</div>
    <div id="child1">perhaps in here,
      <div id="child2">maybe <strong>in</strong> here,
        <div id="child3">or in here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    though here.
  </div>
  <div id="b2">And, don't want to have this returned.</div>

  <button id="btn">btn</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHTML` will return everything inside the div.

```
(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var x = document.getElementById('forkfork').innerHTML;
        console.log(x);
    });
}());
```

`console.log(x)` Will output this:

```
want to be able to select anthing within here
    <div id="child">something else</div>
    <div id="child1">another thing,
        <div id="child2">and another thing,
            <div id="child3">and another thing
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    though here.
```

If you want all text:

```
(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var x = $('#forkfork').text();
        console.log(x);
    });
}());
```

Which will output:

```
want to be able to select anthing within here
    something else
    another thing,
        and another thing,
            and another thing



    though here
```

Comment: Having both `$(function () {})` and `$(document).ready()` is redundant.

Comment: My bad, didn't mean to use $ for the function. Edited

Comment: I only want the selected text within the div, not everything within the div.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself now (`I want to be able to select anything within the "forkfork" div, and have it returned, ideally the raw HTML.` | `I want the selected HTML within the forkfork div, including any selected nested divs.`)

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. I only want the selected text, along with any HTML tags it may include (so if I select some text that contains a bolded part, I want the bold tags included).

Comment: You can either have all the HTML, or only the plaintext (with `$('#forkfork').text()`).

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, neither .innerHTML() nor .text() will return just the text a person has selected.